# If the nonce is 32 bits why the proof of it is difficult?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info, ethereum

I want to know why mining of nonce is difficult?

The nonce is 32 bits (4294967296) and a high level Nvidia graphic card can check and mine it in a second.

why do we need a pool to mine a blockchain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The vast majority of the time, none of the 2^32 possible nonces in a particular block header template will result in the header having a hash that meets the proof-of-work target.  In fact, the probability that this *doesn't* happen equals exactly 1 over the network difficulty.  Right now, that is 1/6,379,265,451,411.

When no nonce succeeds, one must change something else in the block header and start again.  The typical solution is to change the *extranonce* field in the coinbase transaction and recompute the Merkle root.  See [What is the extraNonce?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/what-is-the-extranonce)