# How will mining work after 2140?

Tags: nonce, mining-technical-details

The nonce header of a block has 32 bits. The vast majority of the time, none of the 2^32 nonces will result in a block hash below the target. So to continue mining, miners usually change the [extraNonce](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/what-is-the-extranonce) in the coinbase transaction. But what will happen once all the bitcoins have been mined and there is no coinbase transaction anymore? I know this will only happen in 2140, but have we thought of a way to change the nonce range when it will be the case?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There’s no such thing as a block without a coinbase transaction. Even if the block reward plus fees is zero, it is still a mandatory transaction at the start of every block, it just pays nothing.